# Does a d'Arsonval coil / Oudin coil / "violet ray" electrotherapy device produce a complete circuit?

Tags: electric-circuits, electricity, charge

A few different historical designs exist for "medical" devices that generate a high-frequency oscillating voltage at the open end of a resonator circuit. Solid-state versions are sold on Amazon today, purportedly for skincare. Having looked at some teardowns of these modern versions, I believe they have largely the same design in the resonator portion as the Oudin electromechanical circuits (fig. 3).

[image: circuit diagrams of historical Tesla, d'Arsonval, and Oudin coil devices]

When the electrode of one of these circuits is brought near to a conductor (including a human body), high-voltage (10-50kV) sparks jump between them. **Does the conductor complete a circuit back to the device through some general connection to an ambient "ground" in common with the device?** Or is it more that a conductor is able to donate some loose electrons when the electrode is positively charged, then take on a surplus when the electrode becomes negatively charged, over and over? If that's the case, is it appropriate to say that the system including the resonator, electrode, and sparking conductor are roughly current-neutral and charge-neutral over time?

Particularly interested in any sources that might explain this situation rigorously, haven't found any yet on my own.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.